# How do I load a Weka model in Java?

Tags: java, model, machine-learning, classification, weka

I have saved the result of a Weka classification by right-clicking on the model and selecting "save model". Now, I want to load it and work with it in my Java application. How can I do that? Models could be naive Bayes, decision trees, or regression. I need to use these three models.

Any suggestion or solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example assuming you have a RandomTree model saved to a `model.weka` file (change to whatever classifier and file you have)

```
RandomTree treeClassifier = (RandomTree) SerializationHelper.read(new FileInputStream("model.weka")));
```

Comment: Can anybody confirm if this works? And is it model.weka or weka.model. I have never heard of a .weka file...

Comment: use this guide to save a trainned model file("model.weka") : https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-machine-learning-model-make-predictions-weka/

Answer (score 7):

If you saved a model to a file in WEKA, you can use it reading the generated java object.
Here is an example with Random Forest classifier (previously saved to a file in WEKA):

```
RandomForest rf = (RandomForest) (new ObjectInputStream(PATH_TO_MODEL_FILE)).readObject();
```

Do not forget imports:

```
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.FastVector;
import weka.classifiers.trees.RandomForest;
```

Comment: The constructor ObjectInputStream is undefined.

Comment: @DamirOlejar it is in io: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html

Comment: yes, that is the one that gives an error! Maybe it is not just the path to a file that needs to be there?

Comment: @DamirOlejar I did a ``import java.io.ObjectInputStream;`` and just worked (it comes with Java).

Comment: Then perhaps PATH_TO_MODEL_FILE is misleading. What type is it? How is it initiated ?

Comment: @DamirOlejar this should be replaced by a String that contains the path to the file that contains your model (previously saved in weka by "Save model").

Comment: That is exactly what gives the ObjectInputStream is undefined.

Comment: The constructor ObjectInputStream(String) is undefined error