# how to build an arff file for weka?

Tags: android, classification, weka, document-classification

I'm new in weka, I've to extract statuses from a social network and to analyse them using weka, how to build an arff file which contains those statuses? does weka contains the algorithms for stemming, stopwords and n-gramm or I 've to use other softwares in order to eliminate the unnecessary data before starting classification? and which the utility for weka for android and java, is there a difference in the use of this software ... have u any idea guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not worry about have your data as `arff` file, since Weka supports other input formats. You can simply have your data as `csv` file and imported to Weka. You can export it from Weka as `arff` if you want.

There is a port for Weka to android that you can [download here](https://github.com/rjmarsan/Weka-for-Android), I did use it in my project without a problem. You can train your model in the PC and export it, then use it in android [see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209510/loding-a-weka-model-to-a-java-code) for example code.

Yes, Weka supports [Stemmer algorithms](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Stemmers)

Comment: can you help me to extract tweets from android in a file , connect android and weka  and identify the several attributes to put them in the csv file, I haven't a clue how to begin... have u an example for that or a tutorial to follow it

Comment: Do you have experience in building android apps? How your training file looks like? what is the task you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'll describe the process, the user has to connect to twitter via android, he selects a friend and extract his statuses,I collect several statuses and put them in a database or directly in an arff or csv file,I connect weka to android and do a sentiment analysis on these statuses passig through different algorithms(stopwords, stemming,n-gramm,native bayes and svm)via WEKA to identifiy either its positive or negative sentiment, how can I begin. thank you

Comment: It depend on your dataset size, but doing the actual training on android device might not be feasible due to the limited processing power and memory capacity of the device, so you might consider doing this on a server.

Before you move to android development, begin by doing everything from Weka on your desktop e.g. prepare the data, train different classifiers and evaluate the performance etc. Afterword you can start looking into android side.

Comment: ok I'll try to start with the algorithms that I need to analyse the text , but I'm wondering when I write an algorithme , it'll be support by any machine learning(weka) for example I'm dealing with text in arabic so it exist several stop words in arabic to remove them ,so when I write an algorithme to de this task it 'll be supported by my machine learning for the classification? is that related with datamining, is there any example to follow them ?

Comment: The question is not clear to me. Are you doing this as part of a graduate study (Masters or PhD)? I need to understand the situation to help you better

Comment: hi,I've a csv file but the problem that the arabic statuses didn't appear, tey are represented in form of question marks in the csv file ,I'm wondering if the arff file support the arabic characters or not ?

Comment: You just need to save the file (either csv or arff) with UTF-8 encoding to display Arabic letters correctly

Comment: sorry for disturbing you each time, I want to follow this example  , it's a process with knowledge flow with weka to analyse sentiment [process](http://markahall.blogspot.co.nz/2012/03/sentiment-analysis-with-weka.html) , he starts with this twitter file [twitter.arff](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1pvkpCwTsiSV3dGX2huaHRpdHc/edit) and there is a kfml file which contain configuration [kfml](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1pvkpCwTsiSTHdfWHJ1ZHpJWms/edit), I'm wondering how incorporate this configuration file to configure the several components of weka (SubstringReplacer, SubstringLabeler)

Comment: `SubstringReplacer` and `SubstringLabeler` are available in the developer branch of `Weka`. You have to download the recent code version and run it within eclipse if there is no ready binary.

Comment: I know the place of those components, the kfml file contain the configuration for several components, I've to run it with eclipse ? I can't incorporate this file within weka without eclipse ?

Comment: To compile latest `Weka` you can do it in eclipse, unless you can find a ready compiled `jar` of the latest Weka version.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know about face book but you can get twitter data by using the arff file [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1pvkpCwTsiSd1pyTFZkdWVRdEs5Q1NiQW1mRmF1Zw/edit?pli=1)  As for how to create them there's hundreds of tutorials online : have a look at [this one](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Creating+an+ARFF+file) and see if it helps you.

Hope this helps

Rachel

Comment: I'm assuming that I'll get data from twitter,if I'll use android to get statuses and then put them in a data base,after that,how can I deal with the arff,how to obtain it?can I configure weka with android or just  build the arff file after extraction from the data bse ? just one more question :) the pos and neg written at the end of each statuses in the arff file , which software can give me these result,and which algorithms I've to handle before using weka (stemming,stopwords, features)I'm so confused and I've to finish this project as soon as possible,thanks for your help :)

Comment: go to this address it has sample source code for stemming, stopwords etc. please accept my answer http://massapi.com/class/weka/core/stemmers/Stemmer.java.html

Comment: @ManelAyadi hover beside the answer and you'll see a tick appear. click it.

Comment: but the example that u give to me for the arff file doesn't work with any algorithm (naive bayes , svm) why ?